# My custom WordPress REST API endpoint is returning HTML instead of response

Tags: wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I'm creating my own custom plugin for WordPress Multisite and I need to create a new REST endpoint for my plugin but instead of returning the sites it's returning HTML.

Edit: It works when i use this format of calling

***example.com/index.php?rest_route=/myrestapiendpoint****

Following is my code snippet for creating a new REST endpoint.

```
public function register_routes()
{
    $namespace = 'connectexpress/v1';
    $path = 'getsites';
    register_rest_route($namespace,'/'.$path, [
        array(
            'methods' => "GET",
            'callback' => array($this, 'getAllSites'),
        ),
    ]);
}

public function getAllSites()
{
    $sites = get_sites();
    
    return $sites;
}
```

This is the response I'm getting.

[image: Postman screenshot]

Sorry if it's a dumb question as I'm new to WordPress development and I'm still learning.

Comment: Do you actually have the ["pretty permalinks"](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/) enabled on your site?

Comment: can you send the screenshot of response preview for whole, i want to see what is your response now

Comment: @SallyCJ yes im using the plain one. Edit: i have tried different settings for permalinks and im still getting the same html unless im using the other way of calling.

Comment: @jabbar when using the example.com/index.php?rest_route=/myrestapiendpoint way im actually getting the intended result.

Comment: @Irtisam.A.Rab, try again setting your permalink structure to any of the non-plain structures like `%postname%`, and then purge your site/server cache - see https://wpengine.com/support/cache/. If the same issue persists, then perhaps you should better off consult the hosting tech support and ask for their assistance in making the pretty permalinks work properly.

Comment: @SallyCJ thank you for the support i have tried the solution that you suggested but im still getting the same error, i guess i should contact the support, still thank you for the support.